# Eliminar elementos xml

Tags: c#, xml, xdocument

Hola chicos estoy cargando los tag items del siguiente xml en un dridView :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<grammar xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar" version="1.0" xml:lang="es-MX" mode="voice" tag-format="semantics/1.0" root="grmVoz">
  <rule id="grmVoz" scope="public">
    <ruleref uri="#rule1" />
    <tag>out.cxtag=rules.rule1;out.rule1=rules.rule1;</tag>
  </rule>
  <rule id="rule1">
    <tag>out='';</tag>
    <one-of>
      <item weight="1.0">Ivan Alberto<tag>out+="out1"</tag></item>
      <item weight="1.0">Ivan Alberto2<tag>out+="out2"</tag></item>
      <item weight="1.0">Ivan Alberto3<tag>out+="out3"</tag></item>
      <item weight="1.0">Ivan Alberto4<tag>out+="out4"</tag></item>
    </one-of>
  </rule>
</grammar>
```

y estoy tratando de eliminar el elemento item al cual le doy eliminar desde el boton del grid view:

aca mi codigo :

```
protected void gvGrammars_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
 GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)gvGrammars.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        string valor = row.Cells[0].Text;
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("voiceGrammar.grxml"));
     xdoc.Descendants("grammar").Elements("rule")
        .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("id") == "rule1").Elements("one-of").Elements("item").Where(y=> (string)y.Value == valor)
        .Remove();
xdoc.Save(Server.MapPath("voiceGrammar.grxml"));
    }
```

Pero el archivo xml no se modifica, tambien probe en vez de usar Desendants, con Elements, e igual nada pasa.

Que estoy haciendo mal , muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: No, ese es el problema ya lo separe, y solo al colocar xdoc.Desendanst o xdoc.Elements, el resultado es un arreglo vacio.

Comment: el xdoc si esta cargado con la informacion del xml que esta en la pregunta. osea el archivo se lee y xdoc se carga con el archivo.

Comment: sip, el xdoc esta cargado, ademas que yo soy quien lleno los valores del mismo xml .a travez de un form lleno esos items que se encuentran en el xml

Comment: dale te agradezco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que estas teniendo, es que tu XML tiene un namespace asociado, y vos no lo estas agregando en las busquedas, por lo tanto, no encuentra nada al buscar los nodos.

Para arreglar lo que te esta pasando, agrega la siguiente linea:

```
XNamespace aw = "http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar";
```

y en cada busqueda de un nodo, vas a tener que hacer:

```
aw+"nodoabuscar"
```

Asi, por ejemplo, tu query quedaria asi:

```
xdoc.Descendants(aw+"grammar").Elements(aw+"rule")
    .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("id") == "rule1").Elements(aw+"one-of").Elements(aw+ "item").Where(y => (string)y.FirstNode.ToString() == valor)
    .Remove();
```

Comment: Pruebo y te cuento

Comment: Estas en lo correcto con respecto al nameSpace, otra cosa que corregi es que al sacar el valor en el ultimo where  va : Where(y => (string)y.FirstNode.ToString() == valor) para que lo corrigas en tu respuesta y marcarla como la respuesta a la pregunta. Muchas gracias